# JS stopping flow of control untill asynch setTimeout returns

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

I am attempting to use a synchronization counter and a recursive self invoking function to block flow of control to the remainder of my code until the set time out asynch function calls terminate and increment my synchronization counter. However it turns out that for some reason the setTimeout functions are never even called whether inside the recursive function or even outside of it. Does the recursive call somehow take priority over the setTimeout functions?

```
var localSynchCounter = 0;
(function asynchCall1(){
    //only runs the very first iteration of this function 
    console.log("running..: "+localSynchCounter);
    if (localSynchCounter == 0) {
        console.log("running autonymous first time");
        localSynchCounter ++;

        setTimeout(function() {
            localSynchCounter ++;
            console.log("set time out1 ocmpleted");
        }, 0);

        setTimeout(function() {
            localSynchCounter ++;
            console.log("set time out2 ocmpleted");
        }, 0);
    }

    else if (localSynchCounter == 3){
        console.log("functions have returned");
        return;
    }
    asynchCall1();

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the recursive call somehow take priority over the `setTimeout` functions?

Yes, because it is synchronous (despite the name `asynchCall1`), while the timeouts are asynchonrous.

> However it turns out that for some reason the setTimeout functions are never even called whether inside the recursive function or even outside of it.

They would (they have been "scheduled" for execution), if your script would have terminated. Currently your recursion is unbounded, because `localSynchCounter` is incremented once but never reaches `3` where the call would end.

To make it work, you will need to invoke `asynchCall` asynchronously (from the timeouts):

```
var localCounter = 0;
(function asyncCall(){
    //only runs the very first iteration of this function 
    console.log("running..: "+localCounter);
    if (localCounter == 0) {
        console.log("running autonomous first time");
        localCounter++;

        setTimeout(function() {
            localCounter++;
            console.log("settimeout 1 completed");
            asyncCall();
        }, 0);

        setTimeout(function() {
            localCounter ++;
            console.log("settimeout 2 completed");
            asyncCall();
        }, 0);
    } else if (localCounter == 3){
        console.log("functions have returned");
        return;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, just to clarify however and make sure I am understanding correctly...Even though the flow of control reaches and enters the first if statement, and executes the log "runing....time" , the setTimeouts are not executed because the JS interpreter recognizes asynCall() as an "unbounded" recursive call? Or is there some other reason the code exits the if block before executing the setTimeout calls. 

Thank you for any additional clarification as understanding the flow of control is the real jist of the question for me, rather than a successful implementation. 

:)

Comment: No, the interpreter doesn't do any recognition. It does execute the call to `setTimeout(…, 0)`, which does immediately *schedule* the callback to be invoked *later* ("asynchronously"). And then it does return immediately, continuing with the second `setTimeout` call, leaving the `if` statement, entering the `asynchCall1()` invocation…. The timeout callbacks are waiting to be executed, but they can only be executed *as soon as the current code has finished*. And the problem is that your code never finishes (like an infinite loop).

Comment: Ah now I understand! Thank you :) , Will upvote however it won't go through until I reach 15 rep ;) 

Thanks again.